# PHP: Best way to get a DateTimeImmutable object for a specific time

Tags: php, datetime

So, I have some time values:

```
$year = 2017; $month = 2; $day = 16; $hour = 7; $minute = 24; $second = 10;
```

Does PHP have a natural way to get a DateTimeImmutable object from that?

Is it this?

```
$datetime = new DateTime; // Create DateTime for current time
$datetime->setDate($year, $month, $day);
$datetime->setTime($hour, $minute, $second);
$datetime = DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable($datetime);
```

The constructor only takes a string. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) describes several formats, but none of them is an ISO date or something like that. Am I supposed to choose one arbitrarily, for example "WDDX" (because it doesn't require me to pad values), and format my date accordingly?

```
$datetime = DateTimeImmutable($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.'T'.$hour.':'.$minute.':'.$second$);
```

All these ways feel rather cumbersome. How is this usually done?

**Edit:** I just found another way (the documentation didn't make that easy) that feels quite right:

```
$datetime = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat(DateTimeImmutable::ATOM, $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.'T'.$hour.':'.$minute.':'.$second.'+00:00');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$time = (new DateTimeImmutable)
    ->setTime($hour, $minute, $second)
    ->setDate($year, $month, $day);
```

It's a little bit "shorter" variant of your first example code

Comment: Oh yes, I like that. Remind me to accept the answer in 4 minutes. ;)

Comment: Setter methods on a class that has the word 'immutable' in it makes me shiver.

Comment: @jlh, They really should not. As per the documentation this returns a new DateTimeImmutable without altering the original object.

Comment: They're badly named, at least by current fashions. They should be `wither` methods instead of `setter` methods.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and [DateTimeImmutable::setTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.settimestamp.php)

```
$year = 2017; $month = 2; $day = 16; $hour = 7; $minute = 24; $second = 10;
    $datetime = (new DateTimeImmutable())
             ->setTimestamp(
                   mktime($hour, $minute,$second, $month, $day, $year)
              );
var_dump($datetime);
```

Just an obvious note:

Remember that the DateTimeImmutable object is immutable :), so each method `setSomething` returns a new instance of DateTimeImmutable and it don't change the initial instance.

So

```
$timestamp = 12345;
$datetime = new DateTimeImmutable();
$datetime->setTimestamp($timestamp); // wrong
$datetime = $datetime->setTimestamp($timestamp); // right

// or better
$datetime = (new DateTimeImmutable())->setTimestamp($timestamp);
```